# how to link jtree with jframes

Tags: java, netbeans, jtree

Good day

I am trying to link between the nodes of jtree with its jframe 
were the tree on left and the forum will display on right 
here is the example 
[Jtree and frame](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X6nFC.png)

and here is my codes

```
     JTree tree = new JTree();
 Employee emp = new Employee();
 rectutment rec = new rectutment();
 interview inter = new interview();

         DefaultMutableTreeNode firstLeaf = ((DefaultMutableTreeNode)tree.getModel().getRoot()).getFirstLeaf();
         DefaultTreeModel model = (DefaultTreeModel) tree.getModel();
         DefaultMutableTreeNode root = (DefaultMutableTreeNode) model.getRoot();
         tree.getSelectionModel().setSelectionMode(TreeSelectionModel.SINGLE_TREE_SELECTION);
         root.add(firstLeaf);
         firstLeaf.add(new DefaultMutableTreeNode("firstleaf"));
                model.reload();
                emp.add(tree);
                emp.pack();
                emp.setVisible(true);
                DefaultMutableTreeNode SecondLeaf = ((DefaultMutableTreeNode)tree.getModel().getRoot()).getLastLeaf();
              DefaultTreeModel modelx = (DefaultTreeModel) tree.getModel();
         DefaultMutableTreeNode rootx = (DefaultMutableTreeNode) model.getRoot();
         tree.getSelectionModel().setSelectionMode(TreeSelectionModel.SINGLE_TREE_SELECTION);
         rootx.add(SecondLeaf);
         firstLeaf.add(new DefaultMutableTreeNode("secondleaf"));
         modelx.reload();
                rec.add(tree);
                rec.pack();
                rec.setVisible(true);
                  if (firstLeaf.isNodeDescendant(root)){
             emp.setVisible(true);

         }
                  else 
                        if (firstLeaf.isNodeDescendant(root)){
         {

                  rec.setVisible(false);    

         }

                  if (SecondLeaf.isLeaf()){
             emp.setVisible(true);  
         }
                  else 
         {  
                  rec.setVisible(false);    
         }       
         }
    }
```

Any Idea ?

Comment: You need a 2 different JFrame in one application? By your image i think you need to Jframe with 2 Jpanels. In which left panel will contain the Jtree

Comment: Yes I need 2 different jframes and thats what suppose to be the left panel will consists of tree but how to do so ?

Comment: What are you doing in that tree click event? What exactly are you trying to accomplish? Is there a tree in the right form or are you trying to create a tree there? You need to be way more specific with your question and pretend that we don't have a clue what you're trying to do. Consider a JSplitPane.